# preg_replace a query string parameter

Tags: php, regex

I'm using `file_get_contents` on a fairly large file. In it, I need to find every instance of:

`http://www.example.com/?foo=1&bar=3`

and change it to:

`http://www.example.com?foo=1&bar=4`

My problem is not understand how `preg_replace` will replace only a partial match on my regex and not the entire string. For example, pseudocode looks like the following:

```
 $content = file_get_contents($filename);
 $pattern = '/http:\/\/www\.example\.com/\?foo=1\&bar=(\d+)';
 preg_replace($pattern, "4", $content);
 file_put_contents($filename, $content);
```

I'm almost certain `preg_replace($pattern, "4", $content);` is wrong in this case. What's the right way to just replace the '3' with the '4'here?

Comment: Why not simply use str_replace?

Comment: Because `bar=4` is not static. it might be `bar=10`, `bar=12341324` etc.

Comment: you have missed closing regexp slash, and `preg_replace` will change whole pattern to '4', in your case. if you need to change just a one character, you can use @Enissay solution, but be ready, that his solution will change any digits with any length to '4'. If you need replacing exactly that string, you need additional limiting condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `\K`: resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match

```
$pattern = '/http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/\?foo=1\&bar=\K\d+/';
preg_replace($pattern, "4", $content);
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/eV5uE8/1)

You can also use a lookbehind:

```
$pattern = '/(?<=http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/\?foo=1\&bar=)\d+/';
preg_replace($pattern, "4", $content);
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/eV5uE8/2)

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = file_get_contents($filename);
$pattern = '/http:\/\/www\.example\.com\/\?foo=1\&bar=(\d+)/i';
$content = preg_replace($pattern, "http://www.example.com/?foo=1&bar=4", $content);
file_put_contents($filename, $content);
```